# Android Application Crashing

Tags: android

I'm trying to make my application start another class.

What im trying to learn is how to get another class to run in the background - like if the user opens the application, the application stays running.

I thought if I could try to open another class by using an intent, it would work. When i run my application on the emulator, it just crashes...

Here is the opening:

```
package omg.justry;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
    //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("omg.justtry.PartF**king2");
        startActivity(openStartingPoint);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Here is the **"PartF**king2"** class:

```
package omg.justry;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PartF**king2 extends Activity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
    }
```

The thing is, Eclipse doesn't show any errors. I just exported the app and installed it to the emulator using adb.

I also added the class to the **AndroidManifest** as you see here:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="omg.justry"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="PartF**king2"></activity>
</application>
```

I think its the manifest now that I look at it but whatever i do, it gets an error or crashes with Eclipse not explaining anything.

Comment: There's *nothing* in your logcat?

Comment: I want a mandatory message for **every** poster in the Android category saying _"did you check the logcat ?"_ !!!!!

Comment: I'll go with that: if there isn't an error in the logcat, then that's a bug against the Android platform, I'd wager there is a bug there, and not a bug in Android :-)

Comment: By the way : `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` are mandatory in your onCreate().

Comment: I checked logcat and this came up:

Comment: I checked logcat and this came up: http://i.imgur.com/mJwFn.png

Comment: @jock look at the red lines at logcat

Answer (score 1):

In every class, you `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method MUST contain

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

The super is absolutly mandatory, and the setContentView defines the layout for your activity.

And an Activity cannot "run in the background". Start by reading some Android tutorial, and you'll have some clues about what to do.

Comment: So how do apps like the "Battery Indicator" are able to run "in the background"

Comment: You can use a service for background tasks. Look here [link](http://www.vogella.com/categories/android/androidservices,broadcastreceiverandnotificationmanager.html)

Comment: Got the service working in the background when the device boots up (i made a broadcast that it can do that) but i cant get it start it when i first open the app

Comment: You can add something like `startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));` in the onCreate() method of your main Activity...